# How to Git Blame/Authors a previous revision with Xcode 11?

Tags: xcode, git-blame, xcode11

With Xcode 10.2, I could select the "Authors" view, then select a **previous** git revision to blame from the bottom picker:
[image: picker is available]

But with Xcode 11 beta, when I select the ["Authors" view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hjc1R.png), I'm unable to select a **past** revision to blame because the picker is missing:
[image: picker is missing]

Was that feature removed, or are there new steps to do to *blame* the lines of code for a **past** revision? To illustrate it even more, I'd like to see in Xcode 11 a **past** Blame like GitHub does when you [blame a specific **previous** revision](https://github.com/EFPrefix/EFCountingLabel/blame/b84a92689bd453214c6063c6b6e77f8282e2232a/EFCountingLabel/Classes/EFCountingLabel.swift).

Answer (score 85):

It has been moved here

[image]

[It has been moved here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hjc1R.png)

Comment: Why I don't see the popup menu?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @Cœur, open comparison. You can do it there.

Comment: @artyom.razinov I concur with Cœur, this doesn't answer the question at all. You can't view the authors in the comparison/code review mode, and this answer doesn't show how to select earlier commits within the authors view.

Comment: Agree with @Cœur. It's not obvious how to make this menu appear.

Comment: The question is how to get the Authors on a **previous** revision, not on the current one. (a previous revision, is like when you are in "Code Review" mode)

Answer (score 35):

for a git blame version click Editor->Author as it, sure it moved
[image]

you can select[image] the icon located in top-right of Xcode to find a previous revision

Comment: The question is how to get the Authors on a **previous** revision, not on the current one. (a previous revision, is like when you are in "Code Review" mode)

Comment: Xcode is one of the worst development environments ever.

Answer (score 12):

Select the [image] icon in the window title bar to enter "Code Review" mode.

git log (History) is available at Cmd-Alt-2. There you can open a specific commit in code review mode via the context menu.

Comment: Thanks for the shortcut to History... could not manage to make it show up. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Mine wasn't showing up until I went to Editor > Show Last Change For Line. After I selected that, the 'Authors' row appeared in Editor > Authors, as well as in the 'Adjust Editor Options' icon in the top right of the page.

Answer (score 5):

Answer to the original question:

You can't. Since Xcode 11, you can only git-blame your working copy. Note: This is my suggested answer after a lot of trying and googling. I'd be happy to learn the opposite.

Further information:

Many people, including me, seem to land on this page because they don't find the git-blame feature AT ALL in Xcode 11.

In Xcode < 10, the version editor came in three flavors: 1) Comparison view (=side-by-side diff), 2) Author (=git-blame) 3) Log. In all three flavors, you could choose a specific revision to look at.

[image: flavors of Xcode 10 version editor]

In Xcode >= 11, the version editor (now called “Code Review”) only encompasses the comparison view (=side-by-side diff). The Code Review mode is toggled on/off with the double arrow button in the tool bar.

[image: Code Review in Xcode 11]

The Authors view (a.k.a. git-blame) is now a side-pane of the normal editor and can be toggled on/off in the Editor main menu. THIS OPTION IS NOT AVAILABLE WHEN YOU ARE IN CODE REVIEW MODE! For me, this caused confusion when looking for the Authors view.

[image]

The fact that the Authors view is not part of the version editor might be the reason that we cannot choose to look at arbitrary revisions. I have filed a suggestion with Apple to re-enable this feature. You should consider to do the same to give the issue more visibility.

Comment: Feel free to share your AssistantID for that request.

Comment: @Cœur: Are you talking about the ID of my feedback ticket with Apple? It's FB8530848. You can cite it in you own feedback.

Answer (score 3):

In Xcode 11, the previous "Authors" menu item doesn't appear by default in the menu set. The simplest way to make it appear is to press the default key bind <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. After that, you'll find that "Minimap", "Authors", and "Code Coverage" now appear in the "Editors" menu.

Comment: The question is how to get the Authors on a **previous** revision, not on the current one. (a previous revision, is like when you are in "Code Review" mode)

Answer (score -1):

If you go up to the top of Xcode, go to "View" and tap on "Show code review", you'll be able to get the git history with author information like on older versions of Xcode.